# How to get image in response with postman

Tags: java, spring, rest, file, controller

I have an endpoint to get the image i uploaded earlier,  it works but not well
[image: Postman response]

I don't know if i can get the image in response

**my controller endpoint:**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
@GetMapping(value = "{messageId}/files/{file_name}")
    public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("messageId") Integer id,@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new FileSystemResource(messageService.getImage(id,fileName));
    }
```

**Response headers:**

[image: Response headers]

Answer (score 0):

[Postman example to save image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWKsw.png)

Click on 'Save Response', then 'Save to a file' with the extension you need.
Luck!